# Communication Timeout Disconnect status 8 after Notifications Enabled (Android 7.1.2)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'm developing a Android Application to control a small device over BLE. The app is more or less finished, but during testing we noticed some weird behaviour. On most phones there are no issues, but on Android 7.1.2 the app keeps disconnecting after notifications are enabled.

The App works perfectly on most phones we tested on, but on Android 7.1.2 the phones disconnect with status 8 (connection timeout) once notifications are enabled.

We are using the RN4870 michrochip module, which might have some issues with it, seeing as when we wrote a simulated peripheral app to run on another phone, the problem phone connected and remained connected after notifications were enabled.

From further reading, the primary issue seems to be with the connection parameters being set to 20 seconds for supervision timeout on the problem phones, which appeared to cause issues for other developers and has appeared in various bug reports for google.

-- edit -- 
A link to the hci snoop file,
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XzzwfhVGoZ__sP7R4BkMwnU-ahOgR8-a

Thanks for advance for any help, and if anyone requires anything to be edited feel free to let me know (my first forum post).

Comment: Could you post the hci snoop log captured on the Android device? If you have a BLE sniffer that would be good also.

Comment: @Emil I have the snoop log file now added, unfortunately I do not have access to a BLE Sniffer.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth error code 0x08 (Connection Timeout) simply means that the two Bluetooth chips lost each other. It has nothing to do with the Android software since Android runs on the main CPU (in another chip). Having notifications enabled or not should also not make any difference, other than the fact that some data is being sent over the link to set that up.

The timeout of 20 seconds has been reduced to 5 seconds in newer Android versions since as you noticed 20 seconds are too much for most cases. It is however not a bug, just a feature.

If you get a BLE sniffer you should be able to figure out which device you should blame.

Comment: When the devices are connected, they remain connected with no issues. But the minute the notifications are enabled, the phone and device will disconnect due to timeout. But when this is tried on any other Android Version there are no issues. Surely the notifications affect this some how

Comment: Well that's like saying the wifi connection breaks down as soon as you go to a website that enables websockets. Maybe the BLE device starts to do some stuff internally when notifications are enabled that affects radio performance, but it's impossible to speculate.